# Puppet-Docker Service Error undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: puppet, docker

I have a fresh install of the garethr-docker repo using command

`puppet module install garethr/docker.`

My puppet nodes.pp that I am running is very very simple:
`include 'docker'`

The logs look like they initialize the conf correctly; however, it's unable to reschedule the service.  Please see the logs below
`debug: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]/content: Executing 'diff -u /etc/init/docker.conf /tmp/puppet-file20140305-9166-j634yb-0'
notice: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]/content:
--- /etc/init/docker.conf       2014-03-05 18:00:12.141549000 +0000
+++ /tmp/puppet-file20140305-9166-j634yb-0      2014-03-05 18:08:46.997549000 +0000
@@ -6,6 +6,6 @@
 respawn`

script
-  /usr/bin/docker -d -g /dap-home/docker  -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
+  /usr/bin/docker -d   -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
 end script

debug: Finishing transaction 70136334948320
info: FileBucket got a duplicate file {md5}35cd6455aae3a3bc020b4db1e9839271
info: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]: Filebucketed /etc/init/docker.conf to puppet with sum 35cd6455aae3a3bc020b4db1e9839271
notice: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}35cd6455aae3a3bc020b4db1e9839271' to '{md5}e6ce3c01ccf99456fc57176f1895f808'
info: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]: Scheduling refresh of Service[docker]
debug: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/File[/etc/init/docker.conf]: The container Class[Docker::Service] will propagate my refresh event
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: Executing '/sbin/status docker'
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: Executing '/sbin/initctl --version'
err: /Stage[main]/Docker::Service/Service[docker]: Could not evaluate: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

---

It should be noted (not that it really matters), that he machine that docker is being installed on is in fact a Docker container.  The container that is the puppet agent is being run with the -privileged.

Comment: You are running Docker in Docker. Maybe you can find some hints / good practices in this project https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind. Jerome does some things in the startup script that you may need to do as well?

Comment: okay good call.  thank you for the input.  so it looks like there could be a couple of things to check.